# Upload em lote Asp.net MVC5

Tags: c#, upload, multiple-file-upload

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando desenvolver um sistema web que funciona como uma rede social voltada para mensagens.

Tendo as classes `usuario.cs` e `Informacao.cs` (que funciona como uma mensagem), preciso disponibilizar anexos nessas informações, as mensagens são divulgadas na página de cada usuário, como páginas de um blog. Um usuário pode enviar vários arquivos junto com a mensagem para outro usuário, a parte das mensagens já tenho, o que preciso agora é implementar os anexos.
O usuário deve poder enviar anexos em suas mensagens e baixar anexos em outras mensagens.

Que tipo de atributo preciso? O que é mais "saudável" para o sistema, arquivos salvos no banco ou arquivos salvos em um diretório reservado?

Não quero o código do controlador todo pronto, preciso de indicações apenas, que tipo de atributo usar, precauções, dicas da forma mais limpa de fazer isso, esse tipo de ajuda.

**Informacao.cs**

```
public class Informacao
    {
        [Key]
        public int InformacaoID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Digite algo.")]
        public String Mensagem { get; set; }

        public virtual Usuario Autor { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime DataPublicacao { get; set; }


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> O usuário deve poder enviar anexos em suas mensagens e baixar anexos em outras mensagens.

Utilize para isso o [Backload](https://github.com/blackcity/Backload). Ele funciona com a maioria dos plugins de upload múltiplo em JS disponíveis. [Ele tem pacote NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Backload/). Ele é freemium: não paga nada pra usar, mas as melhores funções são pagas.

> O que é mais "saudável" para o sistema, arquivos salvos no banco ou arquivos salvos em um diretório reservado?

Depende do tamanho dos arquivos. O banco de dados não prevê hospedar arquivos muito grandes. Para arquivos pequenos não há tanto problema. Também é preciso analisar a quantidade de arquivos usados. Se forem em número muito grande, o sistema de arquivos ainda é uma opção melhor. Parece ser o seu caso.

> Não quero o código do controlador todo pronto, preciso de indicações apenas, que tipo de atributo usar, precauções, dicas da forma mais limpa de fazer isso, esse tipo de ajuda.

Um bom plugin JS para isso é o [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). [Ele tem pacote NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.FileUpload/). Integra facilmente com o Backload. Uma demonstração pode ser obtida abrindo um projeto novo no Visual Studio e instalando [este outro pacote NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Backload.Demo/). Aí basta ler os exemplos e executar o código.

Na modelagem do domínio, crie um *Model* chamado `InformacaoAnexo`, e estabeleça cardinalidade de N para 1 com `Informacao`.